# Flutter - Drawer menu behind WebViewScaffold

Tags: dart, flutter

i have class stateLessWidget, where i would like:

1) Load a web page with a URL (it works well)
2) Use a Drawer Menu (it works well)

**THE ISSUE:** My drawer menu is behind the view :( .

Maybe because the WebviewScaffold load later drawer menu ?

Thank you guys!

**my Homepage Stateless widget**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
              'Benvenuto',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF4035b1),
        ),

        drawer: Drawer(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  accountName: Text('TEST.IT', style: TextStyle(color:Color(0xFFFFFFFF))),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Color(0xFF584CD1),
                            Color(0xFF0fd1c0)
                          ],
                          begin: FractionalOffset(0.4, 0.2),
                          end: FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.6),
                          stops: [0.0, 0.9],
                          tileMode: TileMode.clamp
                      )
                  ),
                  accountEmail: Text("TEST TEXT", style: TextStyle(color:Color(0xFFFFFFFF))),
                  currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 50.0,
                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF778899),
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://domain.it/images/user.jpg"),
                  )
              ),
              new Column(children: drawerOptions)
            ],
          ),
        ),

        body: WebviewScaffold(
          url: "https://domain.it/api/api_booking",
          withJavascript: true,
          headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenAccess},
          /*appBar: new AppBar(
                title: Text("Test page"),
              ),*/
          withZoom: true,
          withLocalStorage: true,
          hidden: true,
        )
    );
    // return
  }
```

[image]

Comment: did you fixed this?

Comment: yes let me send you the code

Comment: @DiegoCespedes Hello, how did you solve this issue ?

Comment: @DiegoCespedes how do you fix this? Share the code

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `Scaffold` to `WebviewScaffold` and remove the `WebviewScaffold` from the body, what you're doing is nesting the scaffolds.

Comment: a get this sintax error: a named parameter "drawer" isn't defined. The WebviewScaffold doesn't accept drawer paramer :(